# How can I fix this error in my tutorial im working on?

Tags: python, django

Ok so i found out that in Django 3 the TEMPLATE_DIRS is deprecated, so I deleted it, it also looked like the template files I got with Django already had this all updated. so now onto the next issue that has risen up.

The tutorial wants me to ad 
'default': {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 'NAME': 'Luddite.db3, to the databases.
[database issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNjk3.png)
when i do this I get the 
EOL While scanning string literal

So figuring that this book is old i thought this might also be deprecated and deleted it in a test. when i did that i found no errors on the page.
when i went to terminal to create the primary app with $ python manage.py startup ludissues. I now get ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ludissues'
[terminal issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlXap.png)

Answer (score 1):

What version of Django are you running?. TEMPLATE_DIRS was deprecated at ver 1.8

The correct way to set the template path in 1.8 or newer would be the following:

`TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'DIRS': '/path/to/my/templates',
    },
]`

Comment: So what about the media_root and Media_url?

Comment: I should also add that i just input the code you showed and TEMPLATES is still a syntax error apparently.

Comment: @ryokochan Can you update your question with a new code snippet ? and most important what version of Django are you running?

Comment: ok edited and updated question. im beginning to think i cant get this program to work because the book might be completely outta date.